# Border around HTML Faux Columns

Tags: html, css, border

I am working on a webapp and I want to put borders around floating divs which I call faux columns for lack of a better description. I know this is very very basic but for some reason - incompetence maybe - I cannot get this to work

The procedure:
I float two divs left and right. These divs are nested in another div which I want to put a border around.

The code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>StackOvervlow</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      body {
        width: 900px;
      }
      #wrapper {
        border: 2px solid gray;
      }
      #container {
        width: 600px;
        float: left;
        background-color:#678;
      }
      #sidebar {
        width: 200px;
        float: right;
        background-color: bisque;
      }
      #footer {
        clear: both;
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="container">
        <p>Placeholder Text.</p>
        <p>Placeholder Text.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="sidebar">
        <p>Placeholder Text.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      <p>Some footer stuffs</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[The outcome...](http://individual.utoronto.ca/igbanam/test.html)

Please explain why the border shows up as a line and does not go around the two enclosed divs as expected. If you could suggest ways to fix this, I'll appreciate that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

to the CSS for `#wrapper`, demo at: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pPPYR/).

The reason the border collapses to a line is because the floated elements are removed from the document's flow, which means that they essentially occupy no space within their parent element, which, with no contents, collapses. The `overflow: hidden;` causes the parent element to wrap around its children. Though, to be honest, I don't particularly understand *why* that happens.

It's worth having a read of [CSS Floats 101, at A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-floats-101/) for a refresher/primer on CSS floats, though, for pointers on their behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

When you float the element, it does not take up space the same way as it does when it is inline.

The solution is to put a block level element that has clear both attribute at the bottom:

`<div style='clear:both;'></div>`

See detail here: http://jsfiddle.net/billymoon/eDqg5/

Comment: this is also a solution; but if I go with this, there will be some extra markup that may be confusing when i want to refactor. thank you!!

Comment: yes there will be extra markup - but this will work on all browsers. I recommend reading the link posted in David's answer, there are many solutions all with their own merits and pitfalls. It is a good article, and links to other good articles.